# Ceiling lights (fluorescent) takes too long to light

Tags: electrical

My kitchen fluorescent ceiling light does not come on and another (smaller) fluorescent over sink is dim. Both come on later. Now my dishwasher won't come on. When the lights came on, the dishwasher lights came on for a few seconds. I checked the breakers, and I turned them on and off. They seems to be okay. What gives???

Comment: Since there are multiple issues I would be looking for a wiring problem with a broken or loose wire feeding these it could be on the hot or neutral. I would guess that they are all fed by the same breaker.

Answer (score 1):

First, a little bit of a slow start is a good thing -- that is a better-quality ballast "soft-starting" the bulbs.  They light up pre-heaters in the ends of the bulb before striking the arc.  The best programmed-start ballasts actually measure performance, so they know to give the bulbs longer to start.  But this is not that.   To troubleshoot this:

- Change the bulbs, unless you have tested the bulb good in another fixture.
- look around for a "starter" and change the starter if it has one.
- Replace the ballast with a modern electronic ballast.  In this case, if there's a starter, it will be bypassed.  You can leave it in place to avoid an ugly hole.

Far better to get an LED "tube" which fits in the fixture you have.  I recommend getting "direct wire" LED tubes, in which you rewire your fixture to bypass the ballast.  (Don't use "ballast ready" or "drop in" types, because they require you to keep the ballast in the fixture, and it must be working, and it must be a very particular type 0 which is more trouble than it's worth.)

Answer (score 0):

If it were just the light then I would replace the ballast.  Not sure about the dishwasher.  Hopefully someone else will jump in on this.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Fluorescent light tubes have a limited lifetime. There are a couple of effects of ageing

- They get dimmer. A smoky black mark develops at one end of the tube.
- They get harder to start - usually there's a period where they blink on and off a few times before starting.

Unless these tubes are less than a year old, I'd replace them.

I have an office with 64 fluorescent light tubes. Several have lasted more than 15 years, one lasted only 1 year. Most last around 7 years but there is very considerable variation. I wouldn't assume an individual fluorescent tube has a well-defined lifetime.

---

Unlike traditional incandescent tungsten-filament light bulbs, fluorescent light tubes need electronic gear to make them work. There are several generations of this and the oldest used a "starter" that needed replacing periodically.

If your light fittings are old and have starters, I would try replacing them. Starters are rated by power (Watts) - you need a starter that has a higher rating than your tube.

After that, I would consider changing the rest of the electrical gear, usually called a ballast, and available in several forms - magnetic or electronic.

If it comes to this, you might consider replacing the light fittings with a LED based alternative.

---

None of this should affect your dishwasher. Problems with this may be coincidental or indicative of a more serious problem with the circuit.

Comment: The difference in performance in those bulbs in your office could be explained by ballasts. One of the failure modes of ballasts, particularly old heavy magnetic ones, is to prematurely age bulbs.